SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
I am encountering the following error when attempting to connect to my MySQL database using Sequelize and credentials extracted from a .env file:
SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

When I hardcode the credentials directly into config/database.ts, the connection works fine, and the database is successfully connected.
When I extract the credentials from the .env file in config/config.ts, the error occurs.
I have used console.log to verify that the correct credentials are being passed to the Sequelize instance in config/database.ts.
// config/config.ts

import path from "path";
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../.env") });

export = {
    db: {
        host: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        dbname: process.env.DB_NAME,
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    },
};

// config/database.ts
import { Dialect, Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import config from "./config";

const dbName = config.db.dbname as string;
const dbUser = config.db.username as string;
const dbPassword = config.db.password;
const dbHost = config.db.host;
const dbDriver = config.db.dialect as Dialect;
const dbPort = parseInt(config.db.port!);

console.log(dbName, dbUser, dbPassword);

export const sequelizeConnection = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, {
    host: dbHost,
    dialect: dbDriver,
    port: dbPort,
    logging: true,
});

// dbSetup/dbConnection.ts
import { sequelizeConnection } from "../config/database";

const dbConnection = async () => {
await sequelizeConnection
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("DB connect");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error in db connection = ${error}`); //error is comming from here
    });
};

export default dbConnection;

// server.ts
app.listen(3000, async () => {
    console.log(`Listening to port ${3000}`);
    await dbConnection();
});

Why does Sequelize fail to connect to the database when using credentials from the .env file, even though they appear to be correct? How can I resolve this issue?
Trying to connect with sequelize using dotenv file
and there is error while during connection
Edit
DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASS=pass
DB_NAME=dbname
DB_DIALECT=mysql
DB_PORT=port


"even though they appear to be correct?" - As you didn't post the env file, there is no way for us to know if they are actually correct. How did you determine this? FYI: You should never connect as root to your database. Consider creating a new database user with sufficient pemissions.

Check for whitespace at the end of your credentials in the .env file.

@DarkBee please check, I have added .env file too. And thanks for the suggestion for DB user with sufficient permission. But for now I want to connect this as it is.

Did you try to console.log the password and check if no whitespaces or other characters are printed as suggested by OluwafemiSule?
